# Device Communication with VISA work in Python, but not in C++

Tags: python, c++, visa

I'm learning to use VISA (A National Instruments set of modules) to communicate with some NI Devices. I previously used Python, but now I'm also learning to work with C++.

I'm having difficultly connecting to a device using the VISA module in C++, but have no trouble connecting to the device using the PyVisa module in Python.

I've attached two snippets of code that I'm using. The Python code works, the C++ does not, even though they should operate in the same way. Does anyone had idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
###################
# PYVISA COMMANDS #
###################

import visa as vi
import time

try:
    # Create the resource manager
    rm = vi.ResourceManager()
    # Connect to resource from USB
    myI = rm.open_resource('ASRL3::INSTR')

    # Setup resource identities for NanoPZ Control Box
    myI.flow_control = 6
    myI.read_termination = 'CR'
    myI.write_termination = 'CR'
    myI.timeout = 3000
    myI.baud_rate = 19200
    myI.stopbits = 1.0

    myI = rm.open_resource('ASRL3::INSTR')
    myI.write('1MX2') # A Very simple command, this works in Python
except:
    "Hello"

# Close Communications
myI.close()
```

---

```
//////////////
// C++ VISA //
//////////////

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "visa.h"

int main() {

    ViSession defaultRM, instr_NanoPZ; // The device is NanoPZ

    // Open a channel with the VI Module
    viOpenDefaultRM(&defaultRM);
    Sleep(1000);

    // Open a channel with the instrument we want to use
    viOpen(defaultRM, "ASRL3::INSTR", VI_NULL, VI_NULL, &instr_NanoPZ);
    Sleep(1000);

    viSetAttribute(instr_NanoPZ, VI_ATTR_ASRL_BAUD, (ViUInt32) 19200); // Baud Rate
    viSetAttribute(instr_NanoPZ, VI_ATTR_TMO_VALUE, (ViUInt32) 3000); // Timeout
    viSetAttribute(instr_NanoPZ, VI_ATTR_TERMCHAR, 0x0D);
    viSetAttribute(instr_NanoPZ, VI_ATTR_ASRL_FLOW_CNTRL, (ViUInt16) 6); // Flow control
    viSetAttribute(instr_NanoPZ, VI_ATTR_ASRL_STOP_BITS, (ViUInt16) 1.0); // Stop bits

    viOpen(defaultRM, "ASRL3::INSTR", VI_NULL, VI_NULL, &instr_NanoPZ);
    Sleep(1000);

    viPrintf(instr_NanoPZ, "1MX2"); // The same, simple command, does not work in C++
    Sleep(1000);

    viClose(instr_NanoPZ);
    viClose(defaultRM);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it does exist inside a main() function, I was just culling the code to make it easier to read.

Comment: I've put the main() function back into the example

Comment: You are using a `C` API, not a `C++` API that throws exceptions on failures. You need to check the return values to make sure all calls have succeeded.

Comment: I'm not familiar with VISA, but you call `viOpen` twice with `instr_NanoPZ`. Maybe that's an issue. And you really should be checking the return values. What does `viOpen` return? Possible error codes here: http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370131S-01/ni-visa/viopen/

Comment: The [`viOpen()`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370131S-01/ni-visa/openingasession/) returns a status which should be checked.

Comment: This is also something I have tried. The status value returned from viOpen is 0, which indicates a successful connection to the NanoPZ Device.

Comment: Do you get `VI_SUCCESS` from both `viOpen` calls?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I also get an unsuccessful connection when the device is unplugged, so I'm certain the viOpen is connecting to the device.

Comment: And does `viPrintf` also return `VI_SUCCESS`? And does all the `viSetAttribute` calls return `VI_SUCCESS`?

Comment: Hmm, I will check

Comment: Yes, it also returns 0

Comment: `0` tells me nothing since I don't have the values for the macros, but I assume that's `VI_SUCCESS`. Does all the `viSetAttribute` calls return `VI_SUCCESS` too?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. StopBits is not successful

Comment: Always check return values :)

Comment: Yes, so VI_SUCCESS is defined as 0 in the Visa library. Each visa function can return a status int and 0 indicates a successful action. For some reason STOP_BITS is not sending successfully, this might explain the problem

Comment: Btw, are you sure about the `VI_ATTR_TERMCHAR`? Your Python code suggests that `CR` is correct, but the default is `LF` (`0x0A`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viSetAttribute(instr_NanoPZ, VI_ATTR_ASRL_STOP_BITS, (ViUInt16) 1.0);
```

should be

```
viSetAttribute(instr_NanoPZ, VI_ATTR_ASRL_STOP_BITS, VI_ASRL_STOP_ONE);
```

and replace `6` in

```
viSetAttribute(instr_NanoPZ, VI_ATTR_ASRL_FLOW_CNTRL, (ViUInt16) 6);
```

with the macros defining the type of flow control you want.

```
viSetAttribute(instr_NanoPZ, VI_ATTR_ASRL_FLOW_CNTRL, 
               VI_ASRL_FLOW_RTS_CTS | VI_ASRL_FLOW_DTR_DSR);
```

Comment: This was definitely an error that needed fixing. Unfortunately, it's still not working. I will see if there are any other commands that return a failed delivery status.

Comment: Great, and use the predefined macros everywhere where applicable. Since you are learning C++, you could also practice resource management by creating a C++ API for `visa` so that the tedious work of checking return values everywhere can be done once and not everytime you need to work with the interface.